# Django App fails to deploy on AWS ElasticBeanstalk with pywin32==306

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pywin32

I am stuck here since 2 days. Someone please help.

Django App works fine locally but fails to deploy on AWS ElasticBeanstalk with pywin32==306.

Platform: Python 3.11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.8.

I am using windows 11.

Python Version : 3.12.2.

PIP version : 23.3.2.

Please find below requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
awsebcli==3.20.10
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
botocore==1.31.85
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
colorama==0.4.3
distlib==0.3.8
Django==4.2.10
django-bootstrap-v5==1.0.11
filelock==3.13.1
idna==3.6
jmespath==1.0.1
pathspec==0.10.1
platformdirs==4.2.0
psycopg-binary==3.1.17
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pywin32==306
PyYAML==6.0.1
requests==2.31.0
semantic-version==2.8.5
setuptools==69.0.3
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.5
sqlparse==0.4.4
termcolor==1.1.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.26.18
virtualenv==20.25.0
wcwidth==0.1.9
whitenoise==6.6.0
```

Getting the following error:

```
2024/02/15 13:12:10.274129 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==306 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==306
```

Complete AWS Log :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZbS3aVnHS2fg8-e9QDihnhzuHxB_CPDf/view?usp=sharing
```

I upgraded the PIP and also tried **pywin32==306;platform_system == "Windows"** but in vain.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a Windows library on a Linux server?

Comment: It was auto populated in requirements.txt file. Now that I have removed all "win" files, my project is deployed. Thank you..